# Knockout update onClick Mapped ViewModel property

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

1) When a user clicks an anchor inside div with **class='thumbs**'

2) I want to automatically update ViewModel's **IMAGE_PATH and IMAGE_DESCRIPTION**

3) based on clicked thumb **THUMB_PATH** and **THUMB_DESCRIPTION** accordingly and update the UI inside div class='containt'

Short Version: I want Containt div always reflect the clicked thumb details.

Can someone please help me or suggest me resources on how to achieve that while using Knockout's Mapping Plugin?
Thanks in advance!

```
var data=    {
      "ImagesInfo": [
        {
          "IMAGE_PATH": "",
          "IMAGE_DESCRIPTION": "",
          "thumbs": [
            {
              "thumb_id": "1",
              "THUMB_PATH": "url(http://..183.jpg)",
              "THUMB_DESCRIPTION":"here is a car",
              "type": "sponsor"
            },
            {
              "thumb_id": "2",
              "THUMB_PATH": "url(http://..184.jpg)",
              "THUMB_DESCRIPTION":"here is a boat",
              "type": "img"
            },
            {
              "thumb_id": "3",
              "THUMB_PATH": "url(http://..185.jpg)",
              "THUMB_DESCRIPTION":"here is a plane",
              "type": "video"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }

<div id="Images">
<div data-bind="foreach: ViewModelB">
<div class="containt" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <div data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: IMAGE_PATH }"></div>
  <div data-bind="html: IMAGE_DESCRIPTION"></div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="thumbs" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 4px">
  <div data-bind="foreach: thumbs">
      <a class="thumb" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: THUMB_PATH }, attr: { id: thumb_id }"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
 var ViewModelB = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
 ko.applyBindings(ViewModelB, document.getElementById("Images"))
</script>
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to do and understand what is not working.  Please update your question with a better problem statement.

Comment: I hope it's more clear now. Thanks

Comment: It is a bit more clear but I don't even see a proper view model in your code, nor any observableArrays.  Are you sure that ANYTHING is working at this point, or is your question in general how to use Knockout to make it work?

Comment: I'm using Knockout Mapping Plugin that constructs the ViewModel from the JSON until then everything regarding presentation works fine. Now I try to create some events and i face some problems

Comment: You need to create a view model and then assign an observable array inside of your view model to the view, not map a viewmodel to the data directly